# Computation of derivative involving a minimum

Tags: derivatives

Consider the function $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Let $f(x)$ denote the derivative of $F$ at $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Consider two other differentiable functions $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $b:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose I want to compute
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} F\Big(\min\Big\{g(x), b(x)\Big\}\Big).
$$
Assume that $g(x)\neq b(x)$ for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Is it correct that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} F\Big(\min\Big\{g(x), b(x)\Big\}\Big)=\mathbb{1}_{[g(x)<  b(x)]} f(g(x)) \frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x}+\mathbb{1}_{[g(x)>  b(x)]} f(b(x)) \frac{\partial b(x)}{\partial x} \quad ?
$$

Comment: If $g(x) \ne b(x)$ for each $x$ in $\mathbb R$, then either one of them is discontinuous or one of them is always larger than the other.

Comment: But since we're assume $g$ and $b$ are differentiable *on all of $\Bbb R$*, they must be everywhere continuous. A few more comments: Please do not write partial derivative $\partial/\partial x$ when you are dealing with functions of a single variable. (You also forgot half the derivative symbol twice on the right.)

Comment: Thanks. Is the answer to my question"yes"?